# Does Corda node send messages (state change/ health check) to only the participant nodes or to all nodes of the network/zone?

Tags: corda

Does Corda node send messages to only the participant nodes or to all nodes of the network/zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are shared only between participants (and external observers who are added to the transaction on purpose). From the Corda whitepaper (downloadable from [here](https://www.r3.com/white-papers/the-corda-platform-an-introduction-whitepaper/)):

> A transaction between a group of parties **is visible only to them**, and
> to those whose own view of the ledger in the future may depend on verifying
> the validity of this transaction. [...] The foundational object in our concept is a state object, which is a digital document which records the existence, content and current state of an agreement between two or more parties. It is intended to be **shared only with those who have a legitimate reason to see it**.

And from [Corda training](https://training.corda.net/key-concepts/introduction/#peer-to-peer) doc:

> According to R3, "On the grounds of confidentiality, we reject the notion that data should be broadcast to all participants or cumbersome pre-defined groups." **Corda communications are peer-to-peer on a "need-to-know" basis without broadcast**. Need-to-know is quite different from Ethereum's public broadcast, Quorum's private transactions or Hyperledger Fabric's network "channels" approach. In a Corda network, if Alice transacts with Bob, then only Alice and Bob need to know about it, and possibly a regulator.

Comment: Is there a HEALTH check message send to other nodes by a node?

Comment: No, nothing is shared with other nodes. The concept is that the management of the node is responsibility of each entity that participate to the network. A node operator can use some toolings provided by Corda Enterprise, such as the Health Survey Tool, to check the health of its own node, but not other on the network: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/operations/monitoring-logging/monitoring-trouble-shooting.html#corda-health-survey-tool .

Only the Notary can be checked: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.8/notary-healthcheck.html#notary-health-check

Comment: so this means that the transaction can progress with only the participants being alive and available, does not really matter whether other nodes which are not participants are available or not..